# Speeding up selenium processes with not opening pages in all iterations

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a bot that finds features of products from a web page. Then i use these features for make little database. But for every iteration, a page is opening and closing for like 3-4 seconds. I have 300 product to find. Is there a solution in selenium for not open and close a webpage in every iteration?(If you have another ways for speeding up, please write down)

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: @Wonka Can you explain how?

Comment: No without code. Just use variable for driver and manage it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.